# How can I upload my local file from my webpage SharePoint server 2019 on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, modern-experience, 2019

I have a different webpage and I want to put upload button in my webpage and want to upload documents to the SharePoint server using that upload button and language preferable here is JS. I found many solutions for SharePoint Online but I need solution for SharePoint server 2019 can anybody Help me How can I authenticate users and upload their files on SharePoint server after they click on the upload button. JavaScript solution would be good. Can I use file picker SDK here?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a document library and grant users edit permission on that library, then users can upload their files to the library with the pre-built upload button like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/upload-files-and-folders-to-a-library-da549fb1-1fcb-4167-87d0-4693e93cb7a0#ID0EAHAAA=Modern).

If you have other requirements, would you like to provide more detailed information about your scenario?

Comment: Sorry for less clarification I have a different webpage I want to put upload button in my webpage and want to upload documents to the SharePoint server using that upload button and language preferable here is JS